# Find number of mutual edges of vertices in igraph in R

Tags: r, igraph, vertex

This should be straightforward, but I want to obtain the number of mutual edges associated with all the vertices in my graph:

```
library(igraph)
ed <- data.frame(from = c(1,1,2,3,3), to = c(2,3,1,1,2))
ver <- data.frame(id = 1:3)
gr <- graph_from_data_frame(d = ed,vertices = ver, directed = T)
plot(gr)
```

[image: Graph]

I know I can use `which_mutual` for edges, but is there an equivalent command for getting something like this:

```
# vertex  edges  no_mutual
#      1      2          2
#      2      1          1
#      3      2          1
```

**UDPATE:** Corrected inconsistencies in output table as pointed out by emilliman5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a one-liner solution:

```
> table(unlist(strsplit(attr(E(gr)[which_mutual(gr)],"vnames"),"\\|")))/2

1 2 3 
2 1 1
```

It relies on getting the vertex names for each edge in an edgelist as the "vnames" attribute being a "|"-separated string. It then splits on that, then that gives you a table of all vertexes in mutual edges, and each one appears twice per edge so divide by two.

If there's a less hacky way of getting vertex names from an edgelist, I'm sure Gabor knows it.

Here's that trick in more detail:

For your graph `gr`:

```
> E(gr)
+ 5/5 edges (vertex names):
[1] 1->2 1->3 2->1 3->1 3->2
```

You can get vertexes for edges thus:

```
> attr(E(gr),"vnames")
[1] "1|2" "1|3" "2|1" "3|1" "3|2"
```

So my one-liner subsets that edge list my the mutuality criterion, then manipulates the strings.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how well this will scale, but it gets the job done. Your expected table has some inconsistencies so I did the best I could, i.e. vertex 2 only has one originating edge not 2.

```
mutual_edges <- lapply(V(gr), function(x) which_mutual(gr, es = E(gr)[from(x) | to(x)]))
df <- data.frame(Vertex=names(mutual_edges), 
                 Edges=unlist(lapply(V(gr), function(x) length(E(gr)[from(x)]) )), 
                 no_mutual=unlist(lapply(mutual_edges, function(x) sum(x)/2)))
df

#  Vertex Edges no_mutual
#1      1     2         2
#2      2     1         1
#3      3     2         1
```